# Variance of Function of Sample standard deviation

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, variance

I'm trying to calculate Var(s<sub>x</sub>/s<sub>y</sub>), 
where X is distributed N(μ<sub>x</sub>,  θ<sub>x</sub>) and Y is distributed N(μ<sub>y</sub>,  θ<sub>y</sub>).

Note: s<sub>x</sub>, s<sub>y</sub> are the sample standard deviations of X and Y.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how accessible this is to you, this might be more of a long comment than an answer.

If the sample size is $n$, famously $s_x/\sigma_x,\,s_y/\sigma_y$ are $\chi_{n-1}$-distributed, where $X$ has standard deviation $\sigma_x$ etc.; I'm not sure from your notation whether you intend $\theta_x=\sigma_x$ or $\theta_x=\sigma_x^2$. I say "famously"; this is covered if you're taught how to derive the Student's $t$-distribution. In that problem, we show a mean-$0$ normally distributed offset from a sample mean, divided by a $\chi_n$-distributed sample standard deviation, is $t$-distributed.

Although your problem is different, they both require the same technique (if I expand your problem to one of finding the distribution of $s_x/s_y$), as each obtains the distribution of the ratio of two independent variables. (Even when variables aren't independent, if their joint distribution is continuous the resulting PDF is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Derivation) integral.)

In your case, the final result is proportional to the square root of a variable with an $F$-distribution; as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution), $F$-distributions are by definition the ratios of independent $\chi^2$ variables, each scaled to have mean $1$. <strike>The square root of an $F$-distribution will have a folded $t$-distribution.</strike> Correction: that last part is only true in a special case.

As for finding the variance you seek, its evaluation will require you to be *au fait* with the Beta function.